# Facebook-esque 'no connection' banner?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, user-interface

I'm looking for a way of implementing an alert banner like Facebook does when their iPhone app loses connection. If you have the Facebook app for iPhone, switch to airplane mode whilst in the app to see what I mean.

Failing this, I'm looking for a nice tidy way of letting the user know that connection has been lost, whilst still allowing them to navigate the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TSMessages](https://github.com/toursprung/TSMessages) library is for you:)

Comment: Good.Accept if you think, that your question has been answered.

Comment: TSMessage is very good. Only issue is I cannot figure out how to show it in the current view. Any suggestions?